# How do I needed to structure this in order for files to be able to import with each other and the main file?

Tags: python, import

Here is my code:

```
from .Input import Choice27
import os
def New_File():
    file_path = os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\Me\Documents\Project\InputFolder\Test.txt")
    Var1 = str(Choice27.Var[0])
    Var2 = str(Choice27.Var[1])
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        Output = file.read()
        Replace = {'Find1':Var1,'Find2':Var2,}
        for key, value in Replace.items():
            Output = Output.replace(key, value)
```

It is giving me an error ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.
My file structure for this test project is:

```
Project folder
  Main.py
  InputSubFolder
    Input.py
    Output.py
```

I know a beginner amount of python programming but I have never dealt with subfolders with my code. I use vscode for testing and auto-py-to-exe for compiling. I do not have any warnings before testing with vscode and receive no errors on compiling.

I have tried doing absolute pathing Ex. "from Input import Choice27", but I receive the same error.
I have also tried adding **init**.py to the subfolder even though I know it is not needed in my version of python.
On the Main.py, I can call import the modules with "import InputSubFolder.Input as IN, " which works just fine.

What kind of structuring or pathing do I need to do so that each file and subfolder can communicate if needed?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `"Project folder/InputSubFolder"`, create a new file named `__init__.py` (two underscores before and after init keyword) and add following code:

```
from .Input import Choice27
```

Now inside `Main.py`, you can access `Choice27`  like this:

```
from InputSubFolder import Choice27
```

Adding `__init__.py` in a directory makes that directory a local Python package, containing all exportable classes, functions and variables which needs to be imported in some other Python file.

At the end, your project structure should be:

```
Project folder
  Main.py
  InputSubFolder
    __init__.py
    Input.py
    Output.py
```